# Integrability condition

Tags: probability, integration, functions, expectation

Suppose that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}f^{2}(t)dt <K
\end{align}
Does it also hold that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}f^{2}(t)dt <K
\end{align}
? Here, T, K>0 are
 fixed. I am a bit confused !

Comment: I guess that the property \begin{align} \mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}f^{2}(t)dt = \int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{E}f^{2}(t)dt  \end{align}  is the key here

Comment: What does $\mathbb{E}$ refer to here? Expectation? If yes, what is stochastic?

Comment: I apologize. Yes it denotes expectation and $f$ is a stochastic process

Comment: Actually, to me $\int_0^T f^2(x)dx$ is a number. Then $$\mathbb E \int_0^T f^2(x)dx=\int_0^T f^2(x)dx<\infty. $$ May be I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some remarks. Let $X$ denote any nonnegative random variable.

- If $E(X)$ is finite then $P(X\lt\infty)=1$.

  *Proof:* $[X=\infty]\subseteq[X\geqslant n]$ for every $n$ and $P(X\geqslant n)\leqslant E(X)/n$ by Markov inequality, QED.
- On the other hand, $E(X)\leqslant K$ with $K\gt0$ does not imply that $P(X\leqslant K)=1$. Counterexample: $X$ uniform on $(0,2K)$.
- Finally, the statement "$X\leqslant K$" can only mean that $[X\leqslant K]=\Omega$ or that $P(X\leqslant K)=1$. The latter is usually referred to as "$X\leqslant K$ almost surely".

Now, apply these remarks to the nonnegative random variable $X=\displaystyle\int_0^Tf^2(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: thank you much, You made it very clear !